# JTable get Database index but don't show in table

Tags: java, database, jtable

I have a JTable that I am populating from a database. When a user clicks on a cell and edits it I would like to update the database but I don't know which database row index that information came from.

I know that I could add the database index as a column in my JTable and get the index from there when a cell is updated but is there a way that I can do the same thing without showing the index column to the user? Thanks

Comment: If you wrap each row data into a POJO, you can display the data you want, while still maintaining the data you need